# How to place an image or icon in a button using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using the following to create buttons at runtime:

```
var dynButton = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'button', id:'idDynBtn', class:'clsDynBtn', name:'DynBtn', value:'Tool' });
```

**How to place an icon or image on the button created as above?**

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="button">` can't be an image. `<input type="image" src="...">` can show an image, and `<button><img src="..."></button>` can show an image. See [Input Type image submit form value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935456/input-type-image-submit-form-value)

Answer (score 0):

type=submit is a button.

here is the example
https://jsfiddle.net/t7gvd10c/

```
 var dynButton = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'submit', id:'idDynBtn', class:'clsDynBtn', name:'DynBtn', value:'Tool' });
```

Comment: The button in the instant case is being used for purpose other than form **submit**. So can't use `type: 'submit'` here.

Comment: of course you can, you need to handle click like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/0revhg25/

Comment: This is a round about way of preventing form submit. Should be used where absolutely required. Check the question again. How to place the icon?

Comment: im a little bit confused, why are you using input? what is the purpose? i thought this is an element inside a form

Answer (score 0):

I did it with font awesome and jquery same as follow:

```js
function addButton(txt,icon){
  let btn = document.createElement("button");
  $(btn).html(`<i class="${icon}"></i> ${txt}`);
  $(btn).appendTo($("#btnContainer"));
}
addButton("home","fa fa-home");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div id="btnContainer">

</div>
```

I hope it useful for you.

Comment: Could you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64304391/13823230)?